# Maximise speed of download by IDM

Tags: windows-7, wireless-router, adsl2+

Sir I am from India. My ISP provides 512kbps speed. I am using IDM trial version currently the speed of download is still same 512 kilobits per second or 64KB/S. I am confused that why IDM trial is not increasing my speed....

Comment: Try contacting the IDM software provider for assistance first. http://internetdownloadmanager.com/support/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't increase your speed more than what your ISP provides. It's physically not possible.

You can ask your ISP to increase your download speed.